# Android custom referrer possible?

Tags: android, json, google-analytics, referrer

is sending a custom referrer like this possible ? For example this json string:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.myapp.com&referrer={"parameter1":12345,"parameter2":abcdef}

I want that String in my app, like Campaign Measurement from Google Analytics works.

Thx,
Flavian

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: Reading how analytics are implmented here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder

I want to know if I need to follow this specific format or I can send whatever I want, or is there a way of passing a string exactly as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you need to send a full string on "referrer" parameter, this string will pass (just as it is) by google Play to your app.

You can pass some info parsing the info like:
referrer=1234;abcdef;321;qwer

and in your app, parse again this info.

Hope this helps